# Preventing Laravel database refresh on each PHPUnit test?

Tags: php, laravel, testing, phpunit

Whenever I run `./vendor/bin/phpunit` from the command line, it seems to refresh my database on each tests. Whenever I run individual tests within PHPStorm, everything works as expected.

Whereas within my base TestCase, I'm explicitly not refreshing the database.

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;
    use DatabaseTransactions;
}
```

I want to seed once before my tests run, and maintain that state throughout my tests.

What am I doing wrong? I can't seem to find any answer to this in the official docs.

Comment: Which Laravel version you are on ?

Comment: @AliRaza laravel 9.21.0. The latest one.

Comment: Unless I have misunderstood in which case correct me here, but I wouldn’t want the result of TestA bleeding into TestB. If TestB expects some database data based on the output of TestA, put those tests into a single test.

Comment: @Peppermintology yep, that's why I use database transactions. But I want the database to have some basic data seeded, like roles, types, etc. I don't want to reseed this data before each test.